# Unable to proprerly include Showcase View lib

Tags: maven, github, android-studio, showcaseview

I have trouble including the ShowcaseView library in my Android application with Android Studio.

On the GitHub repo (https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView), it says it should be easy to install with Maven. But when I search for showcaseview, Maven finds no result.

So I clone the repo on my computer and try to include it's library folder as a java library in my project's module dependencies. But when I try to use it in my code, it says

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ShowcaseView'

My guess is because the actual ShowcaseView library is not compiling due to errors (the cloned repo is showing in multiple files the error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

event after adding the NineOldAndroids as a module dependency as showed on the GitHub repo.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

**You shouldn't include library folder as a java library.**

**try following way to add ShowcaseView library as a module to your project:**

Go to **file > Project Structure...**

in the left panel select Modules and in the middle panel click plus icon and then select Import Module
from browsing dialog select path of ShowcaseView library

click next... to finish importing `(but notice the directory /gen of library unchecked)`

Then goto the Library section in left panel and select libs in middle panel

if the library `robolectric-2.2-20130909.210745-40-jar-with-dependencies.jar` existed in right panel then you should remove it.

Goto the Modules section and select your main project module in middle panel and click plus icon in right panel and select `Module Dependency...` then select ShowcaseView library that previously included.

*Now you should rebuild your project...*

Answer (score 0):

Go to ShowcaseView Manifest and change the package name to com.espiandev.showcaseview
the rebuild, re-organize imports, R would resolve to the new package.